# What is the default wm for mac

Tags: macos

I am sorry if this is a stupid question, but which window manager does macOS use?

Comment: Can you add some background about the Problem you are trying to solve here?

Answer (score 1):

There is no separate window manager on macOS, the windowing environment is part of the OS itself.

Comment: oh, stupid me. lol